# Maven plugin artifact filter unimportant dependencies

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-plugin, maven-3, maven-dependency-plugin

I'm developing a Maven plugin and using the `MavenProject` object to access my dependencies with `project.getDependencyArtifacts()`, but this gives my all jar, even the test only jars.

Is there some method to filter all non runtime jar? If I just get the scope and compare for `scope.equals("runtime")` I will throw out the compile and other important dependencies.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the source for the Maven War Plugin.  In particular, the ArtifactsPackagingTask class handles the adding of artifacts to the war:  http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/plugins/tags/maven-war-plugin-2.1.1/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/war/packaging/ArtifactsPackagingTask.java?view=markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not find an existing method for this either so I'm using the following logic. This is a plugin building a customized ear, which adds the needed dependencies to an xml file and include them in the archive. It is using `getArtifacts` instead of `getDependencyArtifacts` since I'm also interested in transitive dependencies.

```
    Collection<Artifact> dependencies = new ArrayList<Artifact>();
    dependencies.addAll(project.getArtifacts());
    for (Iterator<Artifact> it=dependencies.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
        Artifact dependency = it.next();
        String scope = dependency.getScope();
        String type = dependency.getType();
        if (dependency.isOptional() || !"jar".equals(type) || "provided".equals(scope) || "test".equals(scope) || "system".equals(scope)) {
            getLog().debug("Pruning dependency " + dependency);
            it.remove();
        }
    }
```

Comment: getArtifacts returns an empty set. I execute it in another project in the package phase. Is there some trick to get that working?